# How to reduce my url from domain.com/web/home to domain.com/home

Tags: php, symfony

I after the deployment of my Symfony project, I would like to know how can I reduce my url from domain.com/web/home to domain.com/home. I tried to change my .htacces file but I don't really know how to proceed.

Thanks for your answer !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28234763/4514250

Try this.

Comment: Are you using Apache or Nginx?

Comment: I have a share hosting by ovh, so I can't edit my Apache server, I only can change my htacces file

Answer (score 1):

Your web server,   (apache, nginx, other) should point to the 'web' directory, not the one above it.

why,  well,    what happenes when you surf to domain.com/app/config/parameters.yml     ...   these files should *not* be in your web-server folder

Comment: For more details one can also read up in symfony's manual on [web server configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html).