# Take out the "public" part from URL from Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm training in symfony framework and I came with an obstacle. I have this front controller:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class FrontController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="main_page")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('front/index.html.twig');
    }
    
    /**
     * @Route("/public/video-list", name="video_list")
     */
    public function videoList()
    {
        return $this->render('front/video_list.html.twig');
    }
    
    /**
     * @Route("/video-details", name="video_details")
     */
    public function videoDetails()
    {
        return $this->render('front/video_details.html.twig');
    }
    
}
```

And in **index.html.twig** I have the following within some links:

```
 <nav class="my-2 my-md-0 mr-md-3">
   <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="{{ path('video_list') }}">Funny</a>
   <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="{{ path('video_list') }}">Scary</a>
   <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="{{ path('video_list') }}">Unbelievable</a>
   <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="{{ path('video_list') }}">Inspirational</a>
   <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="{{ path('video_list') }}">Motivating</a>
   <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="admin/my_profile.php">My account</a>
</nav>
```

But when I click on those links, I get **object not found**. When I tried the url with *public* inside the URL, like */public/video-list/*, it worked. I would like the application to ignore this *public* part on the URL. I tried to change the route to *public/video-list* but it not worked either.

I am using Xampp on Windows 8.1, using the Symfony Framework version 5.1.2. I have the apache-pack installed with composer. How can I adjust this project to ignore this *public* part?

Comment: Could you add to your post the url generated by path('video_list') ? Beside I personally would avoid using the word public in my url, since the public folder actually exists.

Comment: No need to fool around with Apache.  Just use the [Symfony development server](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#running-symfony-applications).  If you insist on use apache then adjust your xampp setup to point to the public directory and not your project directory.  This is not a Symfony issue.

Comment: Please post your Apache virtual host configuration. It sounds like your `DocumentRoot` is set to the Symfony project path, but it should be set to `/path/to/symfony/public`. For Xampp the default `DocumentRoot` is typically `C:/xamp/htdocs` so you would use `C:/xamp/htdocs/public` if you installed your symfony project in `C:/xamp/htdocs` See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to remove '/web' from url in Symfony application without moving content of 'web' directory to root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230508/is-there-a-way-to-remove-web-from-url-in-symfony-application-without-moving-c)

Comment: Can you show us the route yaml file?

Comment: What string did your `path('video_list')` rendered into?

Comment: path('video_list') translated to "https://localhost/symfony-video-app/video-list";

Comment: Can you show us the folder structure in your document root?

Answer (score -1):

Your route 'video_list' is to `FrontController::videoList` is declared in the annotation:

```php
    /**
     * @Route("/public/video-list", name="video_list")
     */
    public function videoList()
    {
        return $this->render('front/video_list.html.twig');
    }
```

You have annotated your class method `FrontController::videoList` to be a route named "video_list" and has a path "/public/video-list". To remove the "/public" part from the route path, simply modify the `@Route` parameter accordingly:

```php
    /**
     * @Route("/video-list", name="video_list")
     */
    public function videoList()
    {
        return $this->render('front/video_list.html.twig');
    }
```

Then you should then use the ["cache:clear"](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/console/usage.html) command to refresh the cache of your annotations. Then the generated path should be changed.

You may use the ["debug:router"](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#debugging-routes) command to see if the result matches the change.

Comment: We will see if the original poster comes back but I suspect they had the public in there as part of their troubleshooting process.  But maybe not.

Comment: If I take out the part *public* from the route annotation, it do not work as the browser shows me that it can't find the object. When I put the *public* part, it works.
Works: @Route("/public/video_list", [...]
Not works: @Route("/video_list", [...]
Even after the commands to clear the cache